# Accessing User in Entity partial class via OnContextCreated()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

All of my tables have common audit fields: modifiedBy,modifiedDateTime, etc.

I would like to have these automatically set, and can set most of them with the following code:

```
partial class myEntities
{
  partial void OnContextCreated()
  {
     this.SavingChanges += new EventHandler(Entities_SavingChanges);
  }

  private void Entities_SavingChanges(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

     IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> objectStateEntries =
         from ose
         in this.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified)
         where ose.Entity != null
         select ose;

     var auditDate = DateTime.Now;
     var auditUser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;//I wish

     foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in objectStateEntries)
     {
        ReadOnlyCollection<FieldMetadata> fieldsMetaData = entry.CurrentValues.DataRecordInfo.FieldMetadata;
        FieldMetadata modifiedField = fieldsMetaData.Where(f => f.FieldType.Name == "ModifiedBy").FirstOrDefault();
        if (modifiedField.FieldType != null)
        {
           string fieldTypeName = modifiedField.FieldType.TypeUsage.EdmType.Name;
           if (fieldTypeName == PrimitiveTypeKind.String.ToString())
           {
              entry.CurrentValues.SetString(modifiedField.Ordinal, auditUser);
           }
        }
     }

  }
```

}

The problem is that there doesn't appear to be any way to get access to the current user. The app is intranet only, using Windows auth.

Is there a way to either pass in a parameter, or get access to the HttpContext (which doesn't seem like it would be a good idea, but I'm stuck)?  Is there a way to populate the EventArgs with information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check out](http://jmdority.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/using-entity-framework-4-1-dbcontext-change-tracking-for-audit-logging/) the section where the poster has overridden the SaveChanges method (6th code box down on the page). This way you can pass in the UserID and perform your audit and not have to use an event handler.